# How to add time values manually to Pandas dataframe TimeStamp column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` looking like this
df

```
TimeStamp. Column1......Column n.
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
...
```

But I want it like this

```
TimeStamp.            Column1......Column n.
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-02.00:00:00
...
```

How can I add this (00:00:00) to all TimeStamps in the dataframe? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing the initial and expected type of the data (string or true date/datetime) I cannot answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([{"Timestamp":"2017-01-01"},{"Timestamp":"2017-01-01"}],columns=['Timestamp'])
df_new=df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda k:k+" 00:00:00")

Output:
df_new['Timestamp']

0    2017-01-01 00:00:00
1    2017-01-01 00:00:00
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please vote up/accept the answer, if you find it useful! This would help others in making decision.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd  
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  
Age = [10, 20, 30, 40]  

somedate = datetime.date(datetime.now())
DOB = [somedate]  * 4
somelistdata = list(zip(Name, Age, DOB))  

df = pd.DataFrame(somelistdata, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'DOB'])  

# problem statement
print(df)
# solution to your problem
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

## Problem statement

```
  Name  Age         DOB
0    a   10  2019-09-19
1    b   20  2019-09-19
2    c   30  2019-09-19
3    d   40  2019-09-19
```

## Solution

```
  Name  Age               DOB
0    a   10  2019-09-19 00:00:00
1    b   20  2019-09-19 00:00:00
2    c   30  2019-09-19 00:00:00
3    d   40  2019-09-19 00:00:00
```